# Unable to boot windows on cloned SSD, missing bcdedit file, c:\boot directory, etc

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, bcdedit, bcdboot

I am using HP Pavilion i7 6th gen machine. I bought and cloned an NVME m.2 SSD only to realise that my hardware supported just the SATA m.2 internally. I bought a NVME m.2 enclosure and cloned SSD using crucial cloning tool. The clone was reported as successful and has the full partition structure of my original HDD.

I've been unable to boot with SSD while I've disconnected the old HDD.
It appears like the boot might still be pointing at the old partition "c:"

The Windows doesn't allow an installation using the "Media Creation Tool" over USB (my SSD within enclosure is connected via USB 3.0 port)

The system is an UEFI.

Over last couple of days I've tried
`bootrec /fixmbr` (this worked)

`bootrec /fixboot` (Initially gave access denied and later with `bootsect /nt60` sys command)

`bootrec /scanos` (would give 0 number of installations found)

That would also result in
`bootrec /rebuildbcd` being unable to give any positive result.

Initially I was able to view the settings of `bcdedit` for `{bootmgr}` and `{default}` and changed/corrected them to point to `c:` partition on SSD where it exists (windows.exe)

However at some stage `bcdedit` got cleared and no longer gave any results.

I tried the list at [TenForums: "C:\boot missing"](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/124175-c-boot-missing.html) with and without the windows media tool installer USB.
(P.S.:  The startup repair on "Windows USB Installer" from web and "Windows System Recovery" on flash drive from the old HDD didn't solve the boot issue.)

```
diskpart
  sel dis 0
  sel par 1
  del par override
  cre par EFI
  for fs=FAT32 quick
  assign letter=T
  exit

bcdboot C:\Windows /s T: /f ALL 
#  also tried      /s T: /f UEFI
exit
```

All the commands went through however the last command would return me with bcdboot command options list, like with man pages.

Also `bcdboot c:\windows` says `unable to copy/create boot files`.

Please guide me through this.

Thanks

(P.S.: I would have just reinstall Windows at this point, but installer doesn't allow to install over USB and my hardware doesn't have a m.2 slot to read NVME m.2, supports just SATA m.2)

Comment: Windows is not designed to live on a removable media. As such, problems are to be expected when trying to shift a Windows installation to a USB device. — If it's really impossible I don't know. As the Windows Rescue can be booted via USB there should be a trick. // But first you should assure the things coming before the Windows Boot Manager are running smoothly with the USB-NVME. Check: (1) BIOS is still in UEFI mode (2) The USB-NVME m.2 SSD is really seen and offered by the UEFI-BIOS. Preferably you prove it by installing a bootable ISO to the USB-NVME and have a successful boot in UEFI-mode